# How to numerate unique values by arrival

Tags: python, pandas

Consider B is a time line and A is an object. I wish to numerate new/unique objects such that column C will provide the result. To be more precise, given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[700,701,701,702,800,800,800,801],'B':[2,3,5,6,8,1,7,4]}).sort_values(by=['B'])
```

df

```
    A   B
5   800 1
0   700 2
1   701 3
7   801 4
2   701 5
3   702 6
6   800 7
4   800 8
```

desired result:

```
    A   B  C
5   800 1  1
0   700 2  2
1   701 3  3
7   801 4  4
2   701 5  4
3   702 6  5
6   800 7  5
4   800 8  5
```

Logic:
Example: 800 is the first in the list hence he's given 1. Following 700 he's completely new so he gets 2 and so forth. When an item was already seen - we dont count it. Note consecutive for column C 4 and 4 because 701 was seen already.

What have I tried: I added

```
df['temp']=df['A'].shift()
df['C'] = np.where(df['temp']!=df['A'],1,0).cumsum() but I need to sort the result first by A
```

and later sort by B (which revise the order completely)

Comment: First sort on A, iterate on A and then sort by B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].cumcount().eq(0).cumsum()
```

*NB. I couldn't test the code*